# Null different from false in booleans?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, boolean, null

I have a method to construct a post request. That request may have x number of parameters but none of them are mandatory. There are parameters of type boolean (those are passed as strings with values "true" or "false" (not my decision, it is an API).

Here is the problem. My method declaration contains all the parameters that are accepted as part of the post request. The problem is that the request returns different results if a boolean parameter is true, is false or it is not present.

My method id something like

```
-(void) createRequestWithID:(NSString *)id translate(NSNumber *)translate onlyLastVersions:(NSNumber *)onlyLastVersions
```

My method is part of a framework which will be used and called by other developers. That means, I cannot control what they pass to parameters such as translate which is a boolean (I use NSNumber as wrapper).

And here comes the problem. I need to be able to identify if the method was called pasing translate as true, false or nil. Because for those cases, I will have the request as translate="true", translate="false" or translate will be not present in the request.

I need a way to differentiate between true, false and nil.

Testing on gbd to try to find a way to differenciate it I get:

(gdb) p translateFALSE
$5 = (NSNumber *) 0x0

(gdb) p translateNIL
$6 = (NSNumber *) 0x0

(gdb) po translateFALSE
Can't print the description of a NIL object.

(gdb) po translateNIL
Can't print the description of a NIL object.

(gdb) po [translateFALSE class]
Can't print the description of a NIL object.

(gdb) po [translateNIL class]
Can't print the description of a NIL object.

So I see no way to do it.

Comment: All three answers below explain how to do it and mine gives two working code examples. You can't set an object to `false`, that's the same as setting it to `nil`. You see that right in your debugging output, the object pointer points to 0x0 -- NULL. See the documentation for `NSNumber` for creating numbers, but you *must* create the number like: `NSNumber* n = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if( translate ) {
  if( [translate boolValue] ) {
    // translate is present and is set (YES)
  } else {
    // translate is present and is not set (NO)
  }
} else {
  // translate is nil / not present
}
```

If you prefer to have this look more like a three-way branch:

```
if( [translate boolValue] ) {
  // translate is present and is set (YES)
} else if( translate ) {
  // translate is present and is not set (NO)
} else {
  // translate is nil / not present
}
```

Comment: It won't work as nil is evaluated as false and therefore, even being a NSNumber, if the developer passes false the object is nil.

Anyway, I tried this code to confirm (with translate=nil and =false):
NSNumber *translates=nil;
    if( [translates boolValue] ) {
        NSLog(@"YES");
    } else if( translates ) {
        NSLog(@"NO");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"NIL");
    }
}

Both cases, the output was NIL

Comment: @yowie Because you can't set an object pointer to `false`. First of all, your compiler should be complaining about casting an integer to a pointer without a cast. Second, you need to do it like this: `NSNumber* translate = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];` and it will evaluate the middle block.

Comment: @yowie As for designing your framework... tell the programmers that passing nil means that they don't want to set that feature at all and passing an `NSNumber` object set to `false` means they specifically want it to be false. It's up to you to communicate how to use your API properly to the developers and it's up to them to actually use it properly. If you're very worried about it, take an options dictionary instead of passing in straight objects. If the user doesn't set the key for translate, they don't care about it.

Comment: I appreciate your comments and agree as well that ideally developers would pass [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];. Unfortunately I cannot guarantee that and my question is still not answered. Also I can confirm that the compiler doesn't complain by setting an NSNumber to false, not even a warning.

Comment: @yowie It's too bad the compiler isn't generating a warning. Setting a `NSObject` pointer to `false` is exactly the same as setting it to `nil`. This *is* the answer. This is how you test if the object is `YES`, `NO`, or `nil`. You're setting the object pointer to `false` is a programming error on your part. There is only so much you can do in a framework to protect programmers from making programming errors. If you're that worried about it, use a dictionary to pass in the options.

Comment: I see. If as you said and as I was thinking, there is no way to differenciate false from nil because it is exactly the same, I will have to leave it to the programmers and trust there skills. :) Thank you for your help!

Comment: The net-net is that when a user codes `false` for that parameter they are, in fact, specifying `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as NULL (or nil) for a boolean — NULL is a pointer value. An NSNumber can be nil, but an NSNumber representing the BOOL `NO` will not be nil.

Comment: Please see the information I added to the question. GBD shows that passing nil or false to an NSNumber results in the same and that is my problem. If I would be calling the method I would definitely pass an NSNumber object representing NO, but other developers will call it and they may pass just false

Answer (score 1):

If you're passing an NSNumber, that's an object.  You can easily differentiate between having the object or having a nil value.  (Do this *before* you attempt to extract the object value.)

Comment: The problem is that this method is called by other developers. If the pass false or nil, the compiler won't complain, the developer would have done the right thing (passing false because he wants the request containing translate="false" or passing nil because he wants the request without the parameter translate. The problem is that I am not able to differentiate between the developer passing false or nil to know if I need to ignore the parameter in the request or put it to false

Comment: @yowie -- I don't understand your requirement.  Your caller passes an NSNumber true or false if he wants to specify the value, nil otherwise.  You test for nil before you attempt to reference the value of the object.

Comment: That was my first idea. Though, testing for false or nil behaves the same. For example: If(translate==false) behaves the same than if(translate==nil), that is the problem

Comment: No, they do **NOT** behave the same.  A false will not be nil.  Test for nil first.

Comment: yes it is. As I told you I tested it to be sure and you can also see @Jason Coco answer. Thanks though!

Comment: The problem you're experiencing is that Objective-C will allow false to be specified in place of nil (since both evaluate to zero).  The parameter specification is for a pointer to NSNumber, and `false` is not an NSNumber object.  So someone incorrectly coding `false` rather than `[NSNumber numberWithBool:false]` will not get an error message, even though their code is in error.  But there are a dozen different ways to pass true/false/no-answer values on a call, and you can pick a different scheme (like character strings) if you wish.